# Why BlackBoardValue Says Invalid And False? UnrealEngine4

Tags: ai

Think my ai do not move towards the sound because of the blackboard keys , one says invalid and another says false , i think that is the reason.... Enemy Ai[image: BehaviourTRee] should move to the location where sound is heared , here is the photo of BehaviourTree. Look at those 2 keys named "InvestigatePosistion" and "HasHearNoise" its says False and Invalid. so how make them work?